# How to get the value in 2 point decimals?

Tags: typescript, string, numbers, rounding

On console logging the below code :

```
  const returnedValue = Array.from(
    { length: 2 / 0.25 },
    (_, i) => +((i + 1) * 0.25).toFixed(2),
  ).map((item) => ({ value: item, unit: "usd" }));
```

I receive

```
1: {value: 0.5, unit: 'usd'}
2: {value: 0.75, unit: 'usd'}
3: {value: 1, unit: 'usd'}
4: {value: 1.25, unit: 'usd'}
5: {value: 1.5, unit: 'usd'}
6: {value: 1.75, unit: 'usd'}
7: {value: 2, unit: 'usd'}
```

The value needs to be returned as number.

How can I make the result to round to 2 decimals for all the values including 0.5, 1 , 1.5 and 2.

Thank you.

Comment: You can _either_ have a number _or_ a string with two decimals, not both.

Comment: The "value" is a number. The "unit" is a string. Thank you @tkausi

Comment: I got that. You cannot force two decimals on a number however. `1.00` is exactly the same as `1`.

Comment: I know. But the design demands for that. Thank you.

Comment: The design can demand as much as it wants, its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The value of 0.5 logically equals to 0.50, but you will not get a number represented this way in Javascript or typescript:

```js
console.log(0.50)
```

So, if you want to show this value with two decimals, then you do not have a value problem, but a representation problem. You will need to convert this value into a String, like:

```js
console.log(0.5.toFixed(2))
```

This means that whenever you switch from value to representation, you will need to call `.toFixed(2)` and whenever you switch back from representation to value, you may get the invert, via:

```js
console.log(parseFloat("0.50"))
```

However, to avoid doing all this, a common approach is to keep track of what the value was and switch from that to representation ideally only once. You know more about your exact program and whether this is feasible in your case.